# IOS Json parser that retains float value

Tags: ios, json, api, yelp

I'm using Yelps local search api and have tried the native NSJsonserialization class and also JSONKit.  The problem is that I need the full value of the latitude and longitude for each business returned and these two parsers round the lat and long up to 7 digits right of the decimal. This makes for inaccurate locations when I annotate them to a map.

Does anyone know of a good Json parser for IOS I can use that will parse the full value of the coordinate floats?  The only other solution I can think of is parsing the address out of the json data and then sending another call to googles geolocation api to get the correct latitude and longitude but this doesn't seem very efficient.  Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I was confused apparently seven digits to the right is enough.  The problem was that the results I was getting from Yelp were incorrect.  I figured this out after going to yelp.com and actually looking at the map to see my annotations were, in fact, correct.

Steve